# pdo/json longtext sometimes return as null

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, longtext

I've a table with content pulled from a pdf file page wise (separate row for each page).
It works fine but some of my results are returned as null even though the content exists in the table row? Why some are returning as null?

```
$q = isset($_REQUEST['q']) && $_REQUEST['q'] != "" ? $_REQUEST['q'] : null;

$statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT number, content FROM page WHERE folio_id = :folio_id AND content LIKE :q");
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class(new PageVO()));

if($statement->execute(array("folio_id" => $folio_id, "q" => "%" . $q . "%"))) {
    return $statement->fetchAll();
}
```

in my output file

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("search" => $searchVO));
```

Screenshot attached.
[image: json]

[image: mysql database]

After Adding Length Attribute
[image: length]

Comment: `get_class(new PageVO())` <--- what's this? o_O

Comment: get_class(new PageVO()) returns string version of the path of the class with package name, personal preference as I don't want to write strings in the code, (helpful in refactoring)

Comment: "Why some are returning as null?" --- that's easy. Because there is no data that satisfies the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: my question is why some records (content field) are returning as null while there are records in the backend table. content is a longtext field.

Comment: @zerkms how can I avoid having null in my rows? I don't want to display any records with content null.

Comment: you use `if` for implementing conditional logic in php. Or may be `IS NOT NULL` comparison directly in query.

Comment: @zerkms WHERE content LIKE '%the%' shouldn't have included null rows in the very first place.

Comment: my database has no nulls in it, attached a second screenshot

Comment: use `var_dump` to see the **actual values** for the objects you're serializing with `json_encode` (it's actually weird that you're using some intermediate type instead of plain arrays for this kind of task)

Comment: can't see anything on var_dump, is it possible that content has some characters that's causing json_encode to return null, if that's the case how to fix that

Comment: "can't see anything" --- what do you mean by "anything"? A blank screen? Are you aware `json_encode` deals with **only** `utf-8` encoded data?

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the text that's not showing? Maybe create a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Phil, 3rd, 7th, and 9th row (http://pastebin.com/hCJ5Gq8p, http://pastebin.com/VuDEkZvE, http://pastebin.com/mri2p6sX)

Comment: @user2727195: **IT'S NOT** the original (see problematic data) since it's json_encodable without any issues: http://ideone.com/6H2Eya There is a chance you didn't copy some non-visible (or broken) utf-8 characters.

Comment: @zerkms that's quite possible, but the table was populated using pdftotext utility, page by page, and then inserted into the database. my database is utf-8 default collation

Comment: Btw, here is a short demo of how the data might be broken: http://ideone.com/ShmTQa

Comment: @user2727195: "my database is utf-8 default collation" --- encodings have nothing to do with collation. It's just how characters are compared (yep, all charset/encoding stuff is complicated)

Comment: @zerkms Phil it's the utf-8 issue, this line fixed the problem. $this->connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because some of your strings are not properly `utf-8` encoded.

In that case `json_encode` returns `null`.

Comment: how can I encode them, the content is actually getting pulled from pdf files via pdftotext, stored in a .txt file and then submitted to the database.

Comment: @user2727195: it depends. First - find what is broken, then it will be possible to think of a solution.

Comment: @user2727195 I'd start by at least making sure you're using UTF-8 encoding in your database connection. Your PDO constructor `dsn` should have `;charset=utf8`

Comment: ok, I actually added now please review, $this->connection = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->hostname . ';dbname=' . $this->database . ';charset=utf-8', $this->username, $this->password); it says unknown charset

Comment: @user2727195: what "it"? Have you noticed Phil didn't use the dash in the encoding name?

Comment: worked, added this $this->connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Comment: removed dash, dsn works as well. $this->connection = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->hostname . ';dbname=' . $this->database . ";charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password);

Comment: @user2727195: DSN solution is preferred